# List & Object Duplication Issues in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, duplicates

I had asked a question earlier that involved loops and lists and received some great feedback. Unfortunately, I've run into a new issue that I just can't seem to solve by myself. My apologies for the large block of code:

```
import random
from pprint import pprint

petri_dish = []
lst = [y for y in petri_dish if y.status == 1]

turn = 1

class Species:
    #__init__,relocate, fight, and target methods

for n in range(20):
    petri_dish.append(Species(n,0,0,0,0,1))

def reproduce():
    class Offspring(Species):
        pass
    for z in list(petri_dish):
        if z.status == 1 and z.life >= 200:
            petri_dish.append(Offspring('A'+str(z.name),0,0,0,0,1))

def move_around():
    for x in list(petri_dish):
        if turn % 2000 == 0:
            reproduce()
        x.relocate()
        x.target()

while len([y for y in petri_dish if y.status == 1]) > 1:
    turn += 1     
    move_around()

for x in [y for y in petri_dish if y.status == 1]:
    pprint(vars(x))

print turn
```

The idea is to duplicate the "strongest" cells every certain number of turns. The problem is that these cells are being copied too many times; if you run the code a few times, you're bound to see what I'm referring too.

My suspicion is that I'm trying to change a list that I'm iterating over or that I'm somehow incorrectly referencing a list somewhere, but I can't pinpoint the problem spot.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please try to boil your code down to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: In `move_around`, for every cell in the dish, you call `reproduce`. In `reproduce`, for every cell in the dish, You add an offspring to the dish. So if you have 20 cells and all of them have status 1 and life greater than or equal to 200, then you'll get 20*20 = 400 offspring. Is that what you intended?

Comment: The idea is that after a set number of turns (e.g. 2000), any cells in the dish that are alive (status = 1) and have over 200 life will generate a new cell. So If after 2000 turns there are 4 alive cells left in the dish, then there should be 4 more cells generated, creating a total of 8 cells (4 old, 4 new).

Comment: @Kevin is correct. Just try commenting out line 61 and you will see that it works fine, or try debugging the code as I suggested below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this isn't exactly the answer the OP was looking originally looking for, but it might be the correct answer, and if the OP manages to find the issue, then maybe they will think it is the correct answer too.

Try to [debug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging) the code with breakpoints. For ease of use nothing beats [IPython pdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb), although [pdb - Python debugger](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html), and [winpdb](http://winpdb.org/) are also useful. If you are using [Spyder](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/) or [PyDev](http://www.pydev.org/) plugin for [eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) debugging is built into the graphical user interface - just set your breakpoints and go.

For your code:

1. Install Ipdb and its dependencies (IPython, &c.)
2. From the system command line you can use the handy `ipdb` script.

   ```
   ~ $ ipdb --help

   usage: ipdb.py scriptfile [arg] ...
   ~ $ ipdb species.py args
   > ~\species.py(1)<module>()
   ---> 1 import random
        2 from pprint import pprint
        3

   ipdb>
   ```
3. Commands are the same as `pdb` and for any debugger. Type help after the `ipdb>` prompt for a list of commands.

   The basic commands are

   - `n` for *next* to execute the current line and step to the next,
   - `s` or *step* to execute the next line of a called object, such as a function or class constructor or method,
   - `r` to *return* to the caller,
   - `b` to set a `breakpoint`
   - `c` to *continue* execution until the next breakpoint and
   - `q` to *quit* or *exit*

   Get more help by typing `help <cmd>`. EG

   ```
   ipdb> help r
   r(eturn)
   Continue execution until the current function returns.
   ```
4. Set a breakpoint in your code where you think the trouble might be and step through it.

   ```
   ipdb> b 67
   Breakpoint 1 at ~\species.py:67
   ```
5. You can use Python commands and examine variables with few restrictions - `retval`, `rv` and any of the `ipdb` commands will return the result of that `ipdb` call - so use `vars()['<varname>']` instead.
6. List comprehensions in `ipdb` are like for-loops, and so `n` will step through the list comprehension as many times as the length of the iterable.
7. Hit enter/return key to repeat the last `ipdb` command. EG

   ```
   ipdb> n
   > ~\species.py(67)<module>()
        66
   1--> 67 while len([y for y in petri_dish if y.status == 1]) > 1:
        68     turn += 1

   ipdb>
   > ~\species.py(67)<module>()
        66
   1--> 67 while len([y for y in petri_dish if y.status == 1]) > 1:
        68     turn += 1

   ipdb>
   > ~\species.py(69)<module>()
        68     turn += 1
   ---> 69     move_around()
        70

   ipdb> turn
   2
   ```
8. Step into a function to see what it does

   ```
   ipdb> s
   --Call--
   > ~\species.py(60)move_around()
        59
   ---> 60 def move_around():
        61     for x in list(petri_dish):
   ```

Hopefully you get the idea. Learning to use a debugger is going to have more payback than having someone else spot your bug. At the very least, if you can pinpoint where the extra duplicates start appear, then you can ask a more specific question and you will get better answers.

Happy coding!

Comment: @Kevin gave you the answers. Put your breakpoint at line 63 in `move_around()` and when `turn == 2000` you will see that instead of reproducing the strongest just once, you do it twice. Step into `reproduce()` using `s` and you'll see you loop over`petri_dish` once and reproduce all the strongest (life>200) alive (status==1), but `reproduce()` is **already** in a loop from line 61, and so it gets called 20x, creating 20x the number of `Offspring` instead of just once. QED. I hope that you used the debugger.